# Are there are standard actions for ApexPages.Action class in Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, action, apexpage

I am building logic for `Quick Action` on `List View` represented as `Visualforce Page`.
And after some logic proceed I need to **go back to the List View**.
I have found the next piece of code which does it  :

```
public PageReference returnToListView() { 
    return new ApexPages.Action('{!List}').invoke();
}
```

I have found the documentation about it  [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_action.htm) ,
**However I do not understand from where we take the 'List' action ??**
`Are there are standard actions for ApexPages Action in Visualforce Page ?`

I have also found an example with 'save' action :

```
public PageReference someMethod() { 
    return new ApexPages.Action('{!save}').invoke();
}
```

**Could anyone explain it ?

Maybe there are some documentation about it ?**

Any help will be appreciated ,
Thank you

Comment: I assume that is a reference to the [StandardController.save](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm#apex_pages_standardcontroller) method. But not a mechanism I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `{!list}` is for the [VisualForce Standard List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_actions.htm). This controller is available to the page if `recordSetVars` is included as an attribute on the `apex:page`

> **list**  : Returns a `PageReference` object of the standard list page, based on the most recently used list filter for that object when the filterId is not specified by the user.

Other standard actions you can use on list controllers are:

- `cancel`
- `first`
- `last`
- `next`
- `previous`
- `quicksave`
- `save`

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I was looking for!!